# How can I get better results of bounding box using Find Contours of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I want to detect the bonding box of contours in image, Actually I do it with this code.

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]

for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)

cv2.imwrite('contours_cv.png', im)
```

Her is the result that I get it
[image: boundingBox, FindCountour, Opencv]

We can observe that the bounding box are very large and don't fit very well the object.

So me I want to get something like this picture

[image: boundingBox, FindCountour, what i want]

In this case, the boxes fit very well the object and we have the coordinates of all objects
Please how can we do that

Comment: Change `cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)` to `cv2.drawContours(im,[cnt], 0, (36,255,12), 4)`. Also adding your original input image would be helpful

Comment: thank you for your response. It's good as results, but how can we extract the bounding box in this case ?

Comment: you can create a mask and draw the contour onto the mask `import numpy as np`, `mask = np.zeros(im.shape, dtype="np.uint8")` then `cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt], 0, (36,255,12), 4)`

Comment: OK, but I need the bounding box of each contour like the picture two, not draw contours, because it didn't give me any information about the coordinates